# jquery load call to controller and populate div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a div element in my index.cshtml with id #myresults and i am trying to load data through jquery.load method by calling a mvc controller method. But i am not able to get the right syntax.

I am passing a custom object as a parameter as well.

```
var mycustomObject = {
    obj1:value1,
    obj2:value2,
    ..
}
```

The following does not work...(an i have tried other combinations as well..i get server not found error)

```
$("#myresults").load ('@Url.Action("MyActionMethod","Home")',mycustomObject);
```

while the following works

```
$("#myresults").load('/Home/MyActionMethod', mycustomObject);
```

While the last statement works, it works only on localhost.

Whats the right syntax to use for jquery load with Url.Action ?

Comment: This code should work fine.

Comment: its not working as of now..not where its going wrong

Comment: Is the script in an external file? (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: @StephenMuecke really? that could be it..the script is indeed in an external file

Comment: That was it..Thanks @StephenMuecke I should have thought about it..If you could post it as an answer i can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Url.Action()` will always generate the correct url, so if your getting a 404, it means this code is in an external script file. Razor code is not executed in external scripts so your url would literally be the text "@Url.Action("MyActionMethod","Home")".

Options to solve this include

1. moving the code into the view or its layout
2. declaring a global variable in the view - `var url =
   '@Url.Action("MyActionMethod","Home")';` an in the external file use
   `$("#myresults").load(url, mycustomObject);`
3. assign the url to an element as a `data-*` attribute, for example
   `<button type="button" id="loadSomething" data-url="@Url.Action("MyActionMethod","Home")">...</button>`,and in
   the external file

   ```
   $('#loadSomething').click(function() {
       var url = $(this).data('url');
       $("#myresults").load(url, mycustomObject);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the other two options that would work with the external file.

Comment: @stephenMuecke, It really helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Define the div element as:

```
<div id="myresults" onload="loadMyData();"></div>
```

And make the ajax call in your method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadMyData() {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Action(MyActionMethod","Home"))',
                data: { obj1:value1, obj2:value2 },
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myresults').html(result.data);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Failed to load data!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```