# Core MVC and .ajax not sending data to ActionResult in Controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This works fine in MVC4/5, yet for some reason, in MVC Core, I'm receiving NULL at the parameter in the ActionResult. I've also tried it as the "new" JsonResult, same scenario - NULL is what's being received.

It looks good in Fiddler, and JSONLint tells me that it's valid JSON, so I'm baffled as to why I only see NULL and not my data.

Here's the snip for the POST:

```
function saveClip() {
    console.log("Entered form save function");
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = getFormData();
    console.log("After getting the form data: ", formData);
    var toSend = JSON.stringify({ clipData: formData });
    console.log("After stringify: ", toSend);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Clips/SaveClip",
        data: toSend,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Success: ", response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.error("Error: ", response);
        }
    });
};

function getFormData() {
    var publishDate = $("#publishDate").val();
    var category = $("#category").val();
    var headline = $("#headline").val();
    var clipUrl = $("#clipUrl").val();
    var copy = $("#copy").val();
    var notes = $("#notes").val();
    var source = $("#source").val();
    var relatedTo = $("#headlineList").val().length > 0 ? $("#headlineList").val() : null;
    var isNew = $("#isNew").checked ? true : false;

    return {
        PublishDate: publishDate,
        Category: category,
        Headline: headline,
        ClipUrl: clipUrl,
        Copy: copy,
        Notes: notes,
        Source: source,
        RelatedTo: relatedTo,
        IsNew: isNew
    };
};
```

Here's my ActionResult/JsonResult in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveClip(string clipData)
    {
        if (null == clipData)
            return Json("No input received.");

        dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(clipData);

        using (var context = new ClipsSystemContext())
        {
            var clip = new Clip
            {
                PublicationDate = jsonObject.PublicationDate,
                Category = jsonObject.Category,
                Headline = jsonObject.Headline,
                Url = jsonObject.Url,
                Content = jsonObject.Content,
                Notes = jsonObject.Notes,
                Source = jsonObject.Source,
                IsNew = jsonObject.IsNew,
                RelatedTo = jsonObject.RelatedTo,
                AddedBy = Guid.Parse("eed800ab-573f-4453-8fe4-810b8e714edd")
            };

            context.Clip.Add(clip);

            var status = "Clip saved.";
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status = ex.Message;
            }

            return Json(status);
        }
    }
```

And, finally, here's the Raw view from Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:1711/Clips/SaveClip HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1711
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 265
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:1711
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;
Referer: http://localhost:1711/Clips
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ai_user=PqmJn|2016-09-08T23:11:47.542Z
DNT: 1

{"clipData":{"PublishDate":"10/26/2016","Category":"ba6570f4-1316-4dd5-922e-4739eb9c6c64","Headline":"Ajax Top Story","ClipUrl":"http://www.google.com","Copy":"Ajax top story copy","Notes":"test notes","Source":"Wall Street Journal","RelatedTo":null,"IsNew":false}}
```

*** EDIT - 10/28/2106 ***
Here's the class defining the ClipModel and the updated ActionResult:

```
public class ClipModel
{
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Guid Category { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Guid? RelatedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveClip(ClipModel clipData)
{
    if (null == clipData)
        return Json("No input received.");
    using (var context = new ClipsSystemContext())
    {
        var clip = new Clip
        {
            PublicationDate = clipData.PublicationDate,
            Category = clipData.Category,
            Headline = clipData.Headline,
            Url = clipData.Url,
            Content = clipData.Content,
            Notes = clipData.Notes,
            Source = clipData.Source,
            IsNew = clipData.IsNew,
            RelatedTo = clipData.RelatedTo,
            AddedBy = Guid.Parse("eed800ab-573f-4453-8fe4-810b8e714edd")
         };
         context.Clip.Add(clip);
         var status = "Clip saved.";
         try
         {
             context.SaveChanges();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            status = ex.Message;
         }
         return Json(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you creating and object and then trying to bind it to a `string`. Delete the `contentType: "application/json;",` option and use `data: formData,` and change the method to `public ActionResult SaveClip(Clip model)`. And if you have generated your form controls correctly, then its just `data: $('form').serialize(),`. 80% of your code is unnecessary. And ALWAYS use `url: '@Url.Action("SaveClip", "Clips")',` to generate your urls.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm agreed with you, but not always you can use `url: @Url.Action("Action","Controller")`, for example in `.js` files, where razor not works. Maximum what you can do - pass the `url` with parameter.

Comment: @SeM - In those cases you always use `@Url.Action()` to generate the url in the main view and pass it to the external file (e.g. as a global variable or a `data-*` attribute of the element)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good to know, thanks. Can you please explain, why is it a bad practice, or may be bad programming style?

Comment: @SeM, See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159754/jquery-load-call-to-controller-and-populate-div-element/40170472#40170472) for some examples. In OP's case, the code may result in a 404 because of the missing leading `/` (i.e. `/Clips/SaveClip`) once published

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the input...and criticism. I'll take it as constructive. I tried all of your suggestions, including using the new asp-for="<model element name>", so I think I've created the form controls properly...and I'm still receiving a model with nothing by null properties when it hits the controller. Fiddler still shows the values, of course...for some reason, they're just not making it to the controller. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Possibly your model has only fields, not properties (with `{ get; set; }`) You need to show more information, and the code you are currently using.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, Stephen...I checked that, and, no...they're all properties of ClipModel. See code edit above.

Comment: `PublishDate` does not match `PublicationDate` :) But if you have generated your form controls correctly using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PublicationDate)` etc then all your script needs to be is `$.post('@Url.Action("SaveClip", "Clips")', $('form').serialize(), function (response) { ... });` and everything will be correctly bound

Comment: @StephenMuecke I caught that on the PublicationDate. I'm actually using the `<input asp-for="PublicationDate"... />` model (new TagHelpers for Core) instead of the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PublicationDate)` as the two are equivalent. About the only thing I haven't tried is changing from `$.ajax` to `$.post`...but I'll give that a whirl next.

Comment: `<input asp-for...` and `@Html.TextBoxFor(..)` will both produce identical html. And `$.post()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's what I thought...so, still begs the question...why is nothing getting back to the controller. At this point, I really don't know what I'm missing or what else to try. I've done this 1000 times before, even looked at other code that does work in a different project (not Core, though) and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var urlR = '@Url.Action("SaveClip", "Exam")';       
    var formData = getFormData();
    var convertToString = JSON.stringify(formData);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: urlR,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",          
        data: JSON.stringify({ clipData: convertToString }),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");

        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            //hideprogressbar();
        },
        complete: function () {
            //hideprogressbar();
        }
    });
```

Comment: this answer did not resolve the issue. Still receiving NULL at the controller even though Fiddler shows all values present.

Answer (score 0):

Append the [FromBody] attribute to your Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveClip([FromBody]ClipModel clipData)
```